# How to use git format-patch on initial commit

Tags: git, format-patch

I need to get patch file for inital commit (which is not empty) for our review process, but I'm confused as `git format-patch` command only makes it from branch that is on initial commit not including it.

Seems it must be some obvious move but I'm completely missing it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try `git format-patch --root $SHA` (where `$SHA` is that first commit)

Comment: It works for getting a patch file from the first commit only. when getting patch files from all history, it requires two steps: 1) get a patch file from the initial commit, apply it. then gets patch files by running `git format-patch ${SHA1_of_initial_commit)..HEAD`, apply them.

Answer (score 8):

for making patch for a single commit just use

```
git format-patch -1 HEAD # where "1" is a number, not "ell".
```

where "HEAD" could be changed to any other commit, or even hash code. This works even if HEAD is the first commit. I am not sure whether you are asking for this.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this has changed, but

```
git format-patch --root
```

just created all patch files including the initial commit and HEAD. My git version is `2.26.2.windows.1`.

Comment: Yes! This is good. As the poster says, this does All COMMITS from initial commit through to the most recent

I have just run this on git version 2.34.1.windows.1

Thank you