# git format-patch for all the commits to a file

Tags: git, format-patch

I want to get patches for all commits that are made to a file/folder.

I can get the list of commit-id through `git log --format="%H"-- path/to/folder`

Is there a way i can get generate patches from this list.

[edit]:

below code partly solves my problem

`` for c in `git log --format="%H" -- path/to/file`;do 
   git format-patch "$c^1".."$c" -o patches ;
done ``

since format-patch is called individually, i will get patches all numbered 0001-commit-text.patch where i will lose the order of patches. Is there any better solutions

Answer (score 6):

You can try git diff initial_commit_id..latest_commit_id > changes.patch

This is based on this article: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/git-best-practices-upgrading-the-patch-process

For example:

```
git diff ab0b3a55de5..6f5dbbc4187b97
```

Update:
if you provide the path to the specific file as an argument to format-patch it'll only create patches for the commits with changes to that file. So no need for the loop and one-by-one invocation of format-patch.
See example in [format-patch for a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885075/format-patch-for-a-single-file)

So try this:

```
get format-patch from..to -o patches /path/to/file
```

Comment: This will give a single patch. I would like to have patches seperate.

Comment: Then I guess that's been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658313/generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit

Comment: All the answer will be applicable only if i want a range of commits. not if my commits are at random points in the log.

Comment: if you provide the path to the specific file as an argument to format-patch it'll only create patches for the commits with changes to that file. So no need for the loop and one-by-one invocation of format-patch.
See example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885075/format-patch-for-a-single-file

Answer (score 6):

Come up with the below shell script to achieve this. any other answers are welcome.

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=1;
for c in `git log --format="%H" --reverse -- path/to/file`;do
    git format-patch --start-number=$COUNTER "$c^1".."$c" -o patches
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

Answer (score 4):

My slight improvization (just composed) by using only `git`:

```
git format-patch $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)..HEAD -- path/to/file
```

Might not work if the `rev-list --max-parents` returns more than one commit. Used idea from that post:

[How to show first commit by 'git log'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188914/how-to-show-first-commit-by-git-log#5189296)

Comment: I tested on a Linux kernel git repo cloned on a Debian 10 host. Works as advertised. +1.

Comment: Caveat, will "fail", not get the first commit, if the file you want was in the _very first_ commit in the repo.

Comment: Can use `git format-patch --root` (without any SHA) for cases where the file is in the initial / very first commit. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197812/how-to-use-git-format-patch-on-initial-commit

Comment: @sastorsl, nice observation! Replacing the range with this switch in my command generates the complete patch set (even if the file belongs to the initial commit in repository). Just check that. You should post this as an answer, I think :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on the rest of the answers.

If you want all the commits for a file which is in the **initial / very first** commit you must omit the SHA. Even `<SHA>^1` will not "work" in this case.

```bash
git format-patch --root
```

Refering to [How to use git format-patch on initial commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197812/how-to-use-git-format-patch-on-initial-commit)